# Jenkins Plugins Update & Delete at same time

Tags: jenkins

During my Jenkins maintenance time, I tried to "Update" some Plugins & "Uninstall" \"Unpin" some plugins at the same attempt, from "Jenkins -> Plugin Manager -> Updates \ Installed" Tabs and restarted my Jenkins Instance.

Jenkins failed to Load\parse my Config.xml saying below Errors in diff Attempts.

---

```
WARNING jenkins.diagnosis.HsErrPidList 
Failed to list up hs_err_pid files
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.jna.Native.open(Ljava/lang/String;)J
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:236)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
```

---

```
Unable to read c:\jenkins\config.xml
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:246)
at hudson.model.Hudson.executeReactor(Hudson.java:753)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:667)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:607)
at hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:215)
Caused by: hudson.util.IOException2: Unable to read c:\jenkins\config.xml
at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:152)
at hudson.model.Hudson$12.run(Hudson.java:2340)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
at hudson.model.Hudson$4.runTask(Hudson.java:735)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

My Jenkins Instance is Back Online :-)

Solution that worked for me:

I deleted the "DISABLED" files in my "C:\Jenkins->Plugins" (sort by TYPE, look for DISABLED) and Restarted my Jenkins Instance.

It loaded like a Charm. However, Configuration page Didnt load Correctly due to Some Plugins didnt get Updated good. So Identified each Job and re-loaded the Required Plugins.

Finally, used "Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Reload Configuration from Disk" to get back all my Jobs back Online functioning normal.